# Vue.js 2. How to use Vuex in axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, es6-modules

I have an interceptor, in which I'd like to use `Vuex` getters, but, when I'm importing my `store` I receive `undefined`.

Here is my `src/plugins/http.js` code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from '../store'
import axios from 'axios'


axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        if (store.getters['auth/hasAccessToken']) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + store.getters['auth/accessToken']
        }
    }
);
```

Here is my `src/store/index.js` code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    //...
});
```

`import store from '../store'` also not helping. I've tried almost all ways to import, that I know. Nothing helps.

What do I miss?

Comment: Is your store also undefined outside of the interceptor callback or only in the callback?

Comment: @Lunfel looks like both

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using modules to namespace your getters. To isolate where the problem is, why not try doing this without modules first, as in `store.getters.hasAccessToken` and `...accessToken`. If that works, then it might be that you have the module set up correctly, specifically you might have missed `namespaced: true` in the module. See: https://vuex.vuejs.org/modules.html

Don't forget to return the config object in the interceptor also.

For what it's worth, I use something similar and it works fine without modules. Looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../store'

export default class BaseDataService {
  constructor () {
    this.http = axios.create({baseURL: '/api/'})

    this.http.interceptors.request.use(config => {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + store.state.principal.token
      return config
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: But the problem is, that I don't have store at all. It's `undefined`.